# How to add newly fetched items to the top of the list in react native?

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, fetch, jsx

In my project I'm fetching `json` data from server and list within a `card`.But the problem I'm facing is whenever a new item is added to `json data` new item will be rendered at the bottom of the existing `card`.But what I want is it should be populated at the top of existing `cards`.So how do I do that?Following is my sample code for fetch and listing cards.Please help me to find a solution.Any help would be really appreciable.Thank you.

```
    componentWillMount(){

    fetch(GLOBAL.NEW_WORK_REQUEST,{
          method: 'POST',
          headers:{
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body:JSON.stringify({
            name:"name"
          })
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseData) =>
        {
          this.setState({
            work_rq :responseData.data
          })
        });
      }
    }
   ...
   ...
   <View>
          {this.state.work_rq.map(a => (
           <CardSection>
               <TouchableOpacity>
                   <Text style={{fontSize:18,padding:8}}>Work Category:{a.work_type}</Text>
               </TouchableOpacity>
           </CardSection>
              ))}
              </View>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can this using two ways

1) use [`array.reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse), two arrays will not be used.

2) use two arrays 2nd array will be used when you add new data
here I am using 2 states `newdata` and `data` where `newdata` is on the top of the

like this, (2nd approach)

```
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { data: [1, 2, 3], newData: [] };
  }
  handleClick() {
    var data = Math.random();
    this.setState({ newData: this.state.newData.concat(data) });
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.state);
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.newData && this.state.newData.reverse().map(a => {
          return <div>{a}</div>
        })}
        {this.state.data.map(a => {
          return <div>{a}</div>
        })}
        <button
          className={this.state.isToggleOn ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}
          onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e)}>

          {this.state.isToggleOn ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}

        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/setstate-acehia?file=index.js)

1st approach you can simple do array.reverse and all data will be appended in reverse()

Comment: So in my case can I perform `array.reverse ` on `responseData.data` ?

Comment: You can but that will render all data in reverse mode

Comment: Yeah that means newly added item will be the 1st element right?